# Best/Beautifull way to convert from one object to otherone objects in Java

Tags: java, android

i have a question.

In my Java App i have 2 POJO types, one its POJO types with the body of a webservice for parse with GSON, and otherone its my logic model object, in this case objects are equals, but one extends from Entity(Ada Framework, persistence) and objects for webservice doesnt.

This is an example:

This is a webservice object:

```
    package com.firext.android.domain.service;

/**
 * Created by usuario on 14/7/14.
 */
public class Replie {
    private Question question;
    private String reply;
    private int id;

    Replie(Question question, String reply, int id) {
        this.question = question;
        this.reply = reply;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getReply() {
        return reply;
    }

    public void setReply(String reply) {
        this.reply = reply;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And this is the same object for Persistence

```
public class Replie extends Entity {

    @TableField(name = "question", datatype = DATATYPE_ENTITY)
    private Question question;
    @TableField(name = "reply", datatype = DATATYPE_STRING)
    private String reply;
    @TableField(name = "id", datatype = DATATYPE_INTEGER)
    private int id;

    public Replie(Question question, String reply, int id) {
        this.question = question;
        this.reply = reply;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getReply() {
        return reply;
    }

    public void setReply(String reply) {
        this.reply = reply;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I think its a good practise not use same objects for persistence model and services model, because of this i did it.

Then my question its, i need to convert from service object to domain/persistence object, actually i am doing this (Its a very bad way)

```
private void saveWork(com.firext.android.domain.service.Work work) {
        try {
            com.firext.android.domain.Work newWork = new com.firext.android.domain.Work();
            newWork.setWsId(work.getAlertId());
            newWork.setTeam(Utils.getCurrentUserData(context).get("team"));
            newWork.setPassword(work.getPassword());
            newWork.setWorkString(work.getWorkText());
            newWork.setClientId(work.getIdClient());
            newWork.setAddress(work.getAddress());
            newWork.setTown(work.getTown());
            newWork.setProvince(work.getProvince());
            work.setPostalCode(work.getPostalCode());
            newWork.setPhone(work.getPhone());
            newWork.setDownloaded(true);
            newWork.setDate(new Date());
            newWork.setSignPath("");
            newWork.setPhotoList("");
            Report[] reports = new Report[work.getReports().length];
            int z = 0;
            for (com.firext.android.domain.service.Report report : work.getReports()) {
                int j = 0;
                ReplieGroup[] newRepliesGroup = new ReplieGroup[report.getReplyGroup().length];
                for (com.firext.android.domain.service.ReplieGroup replieGroup : report.getReplyGroup()) {
                    Replie[] replies = new Replie[replieGroup.getReplies().length];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (com.firext.android.domain.service.Replie replie : replieGroup.getReplies()) {
                        ReplieType replieType = new ReplieType(replie.getQuestion().getRepluType().getId(), replie.getQuestion().getRepluType().getName());
                        Question question = new Question(replie.getQuestion().getQuestion(), replie.getQuestion().getOrder(), replieType, replie.getQuestion().getId());
                        Replie newReplie = new Replie(question, replie.getReply(), replie.getId());
                        replies[i++] = newReplie;
                    }
                    ReplieGroup newReplieGroup = new ReplieGroup(replieGroup.getQuestionGroup(), replies, replieGroup.getId(), replieGroup.getName());
                    newRepliesGroup[j++] = newReplieGroup;
                }
                Report newReport = new Report(report.getId(), report.getName(), newRepliesGroup);
                reports[z++] = newReport;
            }
            newWork.setReports(reports);
            newWork.setStatus(Entity.STATUS_NEW);
            FirextApplication.getInstance().getDao().worksSet.save(newWork);
        } catch (AdaFrameworkException e) {
            ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(e);
            isRunning = false;
            instance = null;
        }
        update();
    }
```

You can see that i am only convert an object from one package to other.
I think must be any pattern or best way to do it this..this is not efficently.

Anyone has a recomendation?

Answer (score 2):

If you name all necessary variables the same and plan on expanding the classes, I would recommend using reflection:

```
public void saveWork(Class whatever) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException,     IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
    for(java.lang.reflect.Field f : whatever.getClass().getFields()){
        if(this.getClass().getField(f.getName()) != null){
            this.getClass().getField(f.getName()).set(this, f.get(whatever));
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me, usually.

EDIT:
This code takes a class and copies it's value to himself. If you want to copy you can just replace "this" with any class and return it or something like that :)

Comment: You can't replace `this` with an instance of another class. It has to be an object of the same class you used reflection on.

Comment: I ment you can say that Class anotherClass = new Class(); and then replace every "this" with anotherClass

Answer (score 0):

The Dozer library is intended for exactly this sort of thing. It will map beans of one type to beans of another. Because your properties have the same name in both beans it won't need a lot of configuration, but mappings are fully configurable.

See here: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/